# Установка даты при помощи IdSNTP

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Здравствуйте, хочу написать автоСинхронизацию на Delphi

```
 procedure TsinhForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
       ST : _SYSTEMTIME;
    begin
        ST.wYear := 2019;
        ST.wMonth := 5;
        ST.wDay := 14;
        ST.wHour := 8;
        ST.wMinute := 55;
        ST.wSecond := 59;
        SetSystemTime(ST);
    end;
```

Это перманентная установка по нажатию кнопки, а как при нажатии кнопки, с помощью инструмента  IdSNTP, изменить дату/время?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У этого компонента есть специальный метод `SyncTime`, который запрашивает дату с сервера и изменяет системное время, если сервер ответил:

```
uses
  IdSNTP;

procedure SyncTime;
var
  SNTPClient: TIdSNTP;
begin
  SNTPClient := TIdSNTP.Create(nil);
  try
    SNTPClient.Host := 'pool.ntp.org';
    SNTPClient.SyncTime;
  finally
    SNTPClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Если я правильно помню, то программа должна иметь админские права, тогда система позволит изменить время?

Comment: @VladChapl По идее, да, нужны права. Но я работаю под админом и проверить негде. В любом случае, права нужны ровно те же, что и в случае с ручным заданием времени при нажатии на баттон из кода в вопросе.

Comment: >я работаю под админом. В последних версиях Windows (вроде начиная с Vista) админ несколько урезанный. Поэтому нужно специально запускать "Run as administrator". Ну и в коде отслеживать сообщения об ошибках ОС. (Это я к тому, случаю, когда код "не работает".)

Comment: @VladChapl У меня Win8.1. Код из ответа тестировал, дату/время изменяет без дополнительных телодвижений.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас Delphi-7 не урезанная, то в ней есть Indy. В ином случае этот набор можно поставить - он свободно доступен. В последующих версиях Delphi он присутствует и весьма порой полезен.
Если я верно понял вопрос, то реализация будет примерно такая:
На вкладке **Indy Clients** (иногда просто **Indy**) есть компонент `TIdSNTP`, добавляем его на форму, в свойстве host выставляет нужный нам сервер (пусть будет `0.europe.pool.ntp.org`). Теперь ваша процедура будет выглядеть так:

```
procedure TsinhForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ST : _SYSTEMTIME;
  y,m,d,h,mi,s,ms : word;
  dt:TDateTime;
begin
     try
        dt:=IdSNTP1.DateTime;
     except
       //обрабатываем ошибки
     end;
     DecodeDate(dt,y,m,d);
     DecodeTime(dt, h, mi, s, ms);
     ST.wYear := y;
     ST.wMonth := m;
     ST.wDay := d;
     ST.wHour := h;
     ST.wMinute := mi;
     ST.wSecond := s;
     SetSystemTime(ST);
end;
```

Comment: А что делать при "Socket Error #11004"?

Comment: @NickGrom Как правило, ошибка определения имени сервера. Либо вместе имени выставить IP, либо пробовать другой сервер

Comment: @NickGrom У меня эта ошибка возвращается, если я к SNTP-серверу обращаюсь через прокси по имени. Если не пользовать прокси или пользовать, но через IP, ошибки нет.